# How to make project tree layout compact again in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Usually when I see the project tree in intellij it's something like this:
[image]

But look at how my project tree is being displayed with all the vertical lines and extra spacing, almost as in comfort/compact gmail density:

[image]

How can I revert this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231685) in 2019.3.3 update. Please [see this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231685#focus=streamItem-27-3929480.0-0) for the workaround:

> You can change `Tree.rowHeight` property manually. To do that:
>
> 1. Enable [Internal mode](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/internal_actions/enabling_internal.html#setting-internal-mode-in-the-ide-properties-file)
>      (add `idea.is.internal=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and
>      restart the IDE)
> 2. Open Help | Find Action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), find "LaF Defaults" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 3. Find `Tree.rowHeight` property and change it.

Please note that this setting **will not persist after the IDE restart** and you will have to repeat this step until the issue is resolved. Another workaround is to [rollback to 2019.3.2 release](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html).

Comment: This trick no longer works for me in 2021.3